# How can I pass a Value to a method that multiplies said value by ten?

Tags: java, eclipse

With my Tafe work I have to set it up so my Java program asks the user for their name and their Grade Point Average, and then multiplies said average by ten, and display the result. Currently my code looks like this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Name;
    String gradePoint;

    Name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name.", "Input Name", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
     gradePoint = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your grade point average?", "Grade point average", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    System.out.println("Your name is " + Name + ", and your grade point average is " + gradePoint + ", so your book store credit is " + Integer.parseInt(gradePoint)*10);

}
```

I get that this is axiomatically wrong, but I am still quite new to Java. Please tell me any and all changes I must make.

Comment: What's wrong about it?  Are you getting an error?  Unexpected results?  Explain the problem.

Comment: What *prevents it* from compiling and/or running?  "It doesn't appear to be compiling" isn't really something we can help with.  Maybe you're not actually compiling or running it?  What do you do and what fails?

Comment: @SlipperySeal: Parentheses don't automatically parse a string to an int.

Comment: Please post the exact error message that is coming. Also, update your code here as you modify it.

Comment: Your main method signature is wrong. Should be `public static void main(String[] args)`. The second argument you have should be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v taken your code and made a working version which uses dialog boxes only. No System.out on Scanner inputs.  From your comments you seem to be working with a JavaFX project. This isn't JavaFX code, just a regular application...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Please enter your name.", "Input Name", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    String gradePointString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "What is your grade point average?", "Grade point average", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    int gradePoint = Integer.parseInt(gradePointString);
    int x = 10;
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            "Your name is " + name + ", and your grade point average is " + gradePoint +
            ", so your book store credit is " + (gradePoint*x));
}
```

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I do feel really dumb right now. I just haven't been coding for very long so I'm still getting a grasp on things. But your solution has seemed to work so thank you.

Comment: dont feel bad. Java can take a while to get your head around. who would have thought creating a simple program would involve: public class Classname { public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

Comment: and if you are happy with the answer you can mark it as correct :)

Comment: Yeah, it certainly has been a lot for me to take in no doubt. And thank you for the kind words. I have marked your answer as correct. :D